# No internet connection

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v21h1

Installed windows 10 Pro version 21H1

Already connected but windows shows no internet connection

Already tried reinstalling adapter driver

ipconfig and winsock solutions

resetting the network

none of them solved it

but BTW connecting using VPN makes it shows connected but I don't want to use VPN everytime I connect to the internet

Comment: Did you make any privacy-oriented changes?

Comment: No, I didn't do that